# Important Notice for Joomla 3.4.4

Tags: discussion, off-topic

#### This is off topic but important!

> Anyone that manages any sites on Joomla 3.4.4, please update to 3.4.5 if you haven't already, as this fixes a major security vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

If I done changes in the template file, which is index.php of Protostar template, then what I can I do ?
As, updating joomla would replace my this file as well.
Please give your suggestions on what can be done, which doesn't effects my website look and functionality.

Comment: There are no template changes in this update, so you don't have to worry about losing any changes.